# Using nested if statements within a while loop (python)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, while-loop, nested

Here's my code:

```
#Greeting
print('\n---Sales Discount Calculator---\n')

#User Input
packageCount = input('Packages Purchased: ')

#To check whether packageCount is an integer or not
#loop continues until a positive integer is inputted
validInput = False

while (validInput == False):
    if (packageCount.isdigit()):
        packageCount = int(packageCount)
    if (packageCount != 0):
        validInput = True
        print(packageCount)
    else:
        print('Invalid Input. Try again...')
        packageCount = input('Packages Purchased: ')
```

I'm trying to see if the input from the user is a positive integer and also not a zero. I need to check if it's an integer first(the first if-statement) because you can't compare type string to numbers. If it is an integer, then I need to check if it is a zero or not(second if-statement). When the second if-statement is not present, the code checks for both a positive integer and if it's a string or not, but somehow when I include the second if statement and type in a string, it continues without printing the 'Invalid Input'(the else). *This causes issues later on.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it has to do something with the indentation. I tried indenting the second if-statement but it gave me an error :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have two seperate if-else statements. So the first checks for a digit, and sets packageCount to an int explicitly, however if this isn't hit then packageCount stays as a string and continues into the next if statement either way

```
if (packageCount != 0):
```

I believe you probably want to indent this in so your code becomes:

```
#Greeting
print('\n---Sales Discount Calculator---\n')

#User Input
packageCount = input('Packages Purchased: ')

#To check whether packageCount is an integer or not
#loop continues until a positive integer is inputted
validInput = False

while (validInput == False):
    if (packageCount.isdigit()):
        packageCount = int(packageCount)
        if (packageCount != 0):
            validInput = True
            print(packageCount)
        else:
            print('Invalid Input. Try again...')
            packageCount = input('Packages Purchased: ')
    else:
        print('Invalid Input. Try again...')
        packageCount = input('Packages Purchased: ')
```

You will notice you now have repeated code, but I will leave that to you to remove :)

---edit---

The extra indents we have added ensures the second if-else is only called if the first is successful. The reason I've added a new else in is so that the error message and input request is maintained.
So the first if checks for an integer, if this fails (ie. the input was a string), then we hit the second else.
If this succeeds we then check if packageCount != 0 and either succeed or hit the first else in the code.